# Issue with using golang image decode when running it as a scheduled cron job

Tags: macos, image, go, cron

I have this code that will download an AI generated image from a Dall-e URL. It downloads the image saves it as a jpeg and I can see the image and everything correctly.

```
// Download image code
func downloadImage(imageURL, imagePath string) error {
// Send HTTP GET request to download the image
resp, err := http.Get(imageURL)
if err != nil {
return fmt.Errorf("failed to download image: %v", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Create the file to save the image
    file, err := os.Create(imagePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to create file: %v", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    
    // Save the image to the file
    _, err = io.Copy(file, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to save image: %v", err)
    }
    
    return nil

}
```

This image is then given to another method which is meant to take the image file. Use the golang `image.Decode` method and return an image object that I can then use as an image object and add text to it.

```
func addTextToImage(inputImagePath, outputImagePath, text string) error {
    // Open the input image file
    inputImageFile, err := os.Open(inputImagePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to open image: %v", err)
    }
    defer inputImageFile.Close()

    fmt.Println("Input image path to decode: " + inputImagePath)

    // Decode the input image file
    inputImage, _, err := image.Decode(inputImageFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode image: %v", err)
    }
...
```

When I run it myself it works correctly and as planned. When I schedule a cron job to run it then I am getting an error when trying to decode that is the incorrect format. I have imported the `image` package and the `image/jpeg` package from the golang library. Cron has the correct permissions for the image and is able to do this correctly with other JPEGs saved from the internet.

NOTE: I have since discovered that the images from DALL-E are encoded as PNGs so I have to take the response body from the HTTP call and encode it as PNG rather than just copy it and then do the rest of the work on the image as a PNG.

My question is though why was the code working correctly and getting the correct outcome when I ran it myself, but as soon as I was scheduling a cron job to run it then it would not be able to decode the image correctly? Again I checked permissions, and tested on other images it always seemed to work when I ran it myself but not when scheduled on a cron job. I am using a Mac and scheduling the cron job with `crontab -e`. I have it working now when everything is PNG but the inconsistency between what I was seeing when I ran it myself versus scheduled was eating away at me and I was hoping someone could give some insight on to what is happening there.

I tried to run the executable myself in the terminal and the image was able to be decoded. When I run the image on a scheduled cron tab then I am getting an error that it is the wrong format. I expected the same result from it being scheduled or from running it myself. I am running an executable of all my go files in the scheduler and in the terminal. I use absolute file paths and I `CD` into the directory in the crontab to ensure that it's running the correct executable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with go, but often problems like this are due to the minimal environment that cron jobs run in. Does image decoding depend on something like an external library (and an environment variable that says where to find external libraries)? Also, have you tried redirecting error output from the cron job to a file, so you can see if it prints any informative errors?

Comment: Image decoding is a part of the go standard library. I printed the error it just says "incorrect format". It is calling the correct method it's just when I run the executable in my terminal it works fine, but when cron runs it then it is not able to decode the image correctly.

Comment: So if you modify your app to just run `addTextToImage` and run this in your terminal, over an image downloaded by your cron job, does that work? I searched the `image` package (including subfolders) for the word "incorrect" and it's only in comments (so I suspect you have not given us the exact error message?).

Comment: Yes, that would work. That is how I was testing it. The exact error was `image: unknown format`. Which I assume was because it was a PNG image being saved as a JPEG image. The question is why it would throw that error when ran in the crontab but not when ran in the terminal even if being ran on the same image. If it was ran on a different JPEG that was encoded as JPEG it would work correctly in both cron and in terminal.

Comment: Well if your code did not include `import _ "image/png"` then I'd expect that error; the Go image library looks at the image content when determining the format rather than relying on the file extension. I'm afraid that without the ability to duplicate your situation this is going to be hard to answer (my first guess would be that the executable run under cron was not the same as you ran in your terminal).

Comment: No I would rebuild and run both back to back. So they should be the same executable both are pointing to the same location and rebuilt and ran multiple times. I agree I would expect the error, I am trying to understand what is different about the cron environment that would cause this error to appear there and not in my terminal environment. I can confirm the executable was the same as when I added new logging it appeared in both the terminal and cron logs without changing the paths of either after rebuilding.